# Due to invalid ValidateRgn() childs windows do not get WM_PAINT messages

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi, direct2d

I have window with `Button` control, to drawing I use `Direct2D`, important `WindowProc` fragments:

```cpp
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
...
    case WM_CREATE:
        HWND button = CreateWindowExW(0, L"button", L"Send", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 10, 10, 200, 100, hWnd, CONTROL_ID, desc->hInstance, 0);
        break;

    case WM_PAINT:
        render_target->BeginDraw();
        ... rendering stuff ...
        HRESULT result = render_target->EndDraw();

        // Validate region:
        ValidateRgn(hWnd, nullptr); // validate entire client area
        break;
...
}
```

This code doesn't quite work, my child `Button` was not painted. I suppose it doesn't receive `WM_PAINT` message because I validated entire window, hence Window don't ask to repaint the same pixels twice.

So I take that into consideration, and exclude `Button` region from validation:

```cpp
    // Validate region:
    HRGN update = CreateRectRgn(0, 0, 0, 0);
    HRGN button = CreateRectRgn(10, 10, 210, 110);

    GetUpdateRgn(hWnd, update, false); // get update rect
    CombineRgn(update, update, tab, RGN_DIFF); // exclude button region
    ValidateRgn(hWnd, update); // validate window client area (excluding button) to stop receiving WM_MESSAGE
```

Now `Button` still is not painted, what's more I receive `WM_PAINT` in infinite loop, with update region equal `Rgn(10, 10, 210, 110)`. I expected that after `WM_PAINT` in  `WindowProc`, child `Button` should received it and there missing update region will be validated.

---

Everything works if I wrap `WM_PAINT` message in `BeginPaint(hWnd, nullptr)` `EndPaint(hWnd, nullptr)`:

```
    case WM_PAINT:
        ::log << "WINDOW_PAINT_START" << std::endl;
        BeginPaint(hWnd, nullptr); // use BeginPaint from GDI

        render_target->BeginDraw();
        ... rendering stuff ...
        HRESULT result = render_target->EndDraw();

        // Validate region code is not needed anymore because BeginPaint take care of that.
        EndPaint(hWnd, nullptr);
        ::log << "WINDOW_PAINT_END" << std::endl;
        break;
```

It seems to `BeginPaint()` validate update region and trigger `WM_PAINT` for children windows. It should be called in response to `WM_PAINT` even if you don't use `GDI` and it's `PAINTSTRUCT->HDC`.
But if `BeginPaint()` indeed trigger `WM_PAINT` for children windows then my log calling order should looks like `WINDOW_PAINT_START -> BUTTON_PAINT_START -> BUTTON_PAINT_END -> WINDOW_PAINT_END`, in fact looks like `WINDOW_PAINT_START -> WINDOW_PAINT_END -> BUTTON_PAINT_START -> BUTTON_PAINT_END`. So `WM_PAINT` for `Button` is delayed until `WinProc` returns from it's `WM_PAINT`: hence trigger happen outside, hence children drawing happend after main window paint which is in compliance with MSDN.

So exactly in which moment `WM_PAINT` to children windows is dispatched?

Comment: Do you have the `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` style set?

Comment: No. `HWND window = CreateWindowExW(0, window_unique_name, window_title, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, window_size.width, window_size.height, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);`

Comment: `WM_PAINT` is generated only when calling a message retrieval function (see [Even though mouse-move, paint, and timer messages are generated on demand, it’s still possible for one to end up in your queue](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130523-00/?p=4273)). You will not ever observe nested `WM_PAINT` messages.

Comment: @IInspectable okay, but I don't find it relative to my question.

Comment: *"if `BeginPaint()` indeed trigger `WM_PAINT` for children windows"* - My previous comment explained that this won't happen and why it won't happen.

Comment: @IInspectable I see, okay, you right. I think is worth to mention, that `BeginPaint()` does nothing directly, but play part in scheduling children `WM_PAINT` message. See my answer.

Comment: `BeginPaint` surely validates the dirty region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSDN come in some help [Child Window Update Region](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/child-window-update-region):

> **Each child window has an update region**, (...) The system does not set the parent's update region when the child's is set. An application cannot generate a WM_PAINT message for the parent window by invalidating the child window. **Similarly, an application cannot generate a WM_PAINT message for the child by invalidating a portion of the parent's client area** that lies entirely under the child window. In such cases, neither window receives a WM_PAINT message.

About infinite loop mystery: in code you validate/invalidate (manipulate) region for `MainWindow` only, hence after `WindowProc` return -> queue is empty -> region isn't clear -> `WM_PAINT` is sending to window.

If you want generate `WM_MESSAGE` for child window, invalidate child window update region. Remember that origin point (0,0) was changed to relative to **child** update region, it's no longer main(parent) window update region:

```
    HRGN wrong = CreateRectRgn(10, 10, 210, 110); // wrong, will produce GUI artifacts, try and see for yourself (only part if any of button will be painted).
    HRGN good = CreateRectRgn(0, 0, 200, 100); // good, basically it always be Rgn(0,0 width,height) values in region.
    InvalidateRgn(>>>button<<<, good, false); // invalide child window, first param point to button HWND.
```

---

When this invalidation region for child happen?

MSDN in this matter may be misleading(but maybe just you understand it differently), again [Child Window Update Region](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/child-window-update-region):

> A child window's update and visible regions are affected by the child's parent window; this is not true for windows of other styles. **The system often sets the child window's update region when it sets the parent window's update region**, causing the child window to receive WM_PAINT messages when the parent window receives them.

But in reality, this invalidation for children windows doesn't happen when you call `InvalidateRgn(hWnd, ..., ...)` for main window, but in response to `WM_PAINT`, more precisely `BeginPaint(hWnd, ...)` internally do some calculcation on regions and dispatchs invalidation for childs (but I not sure this, it's just my observations).